# Sentence Reverser Help - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I bought a JavaScript book and I'm stuck on a problem. The question asks for a user to enter a string and for it to be reversed.

For example, given this user input.

*"out! monkeys the let Teacher out, school's out, School's '*'

The program will display

'*'School's out, school's out, Teacher let the monkeys out!''*

I was thinking of using the split method to separate the words, but am unsure what to do afterwards.

Comment: you should attempt to do something and see how far you get. If we give you the answer without you attempting anything you won't learn anything

Comment: Split the sentence into words, reverse them, then paste it back together again.

Comment: I decided to give the OP some help with the question to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the sentence into an array and reverse all words. Then join the words together with the `join` method.

```
var string = prompt("Enter a string. We'll reverse it for you");
var reversed = string.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
alert(reversed);
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/d9wc8xsd/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint to get you started: check out the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method.